# Dockerizing Express-MongoDB Atlas (docker-compose)

Tags: node.js, docker, express, mongodb-atlas

My apologies if this is a noob question but, is it possible to configure a docker-compose file to get an already-existing Mongo Atlas database working as part of a docker network?

I have searched in internet but everyone is using new local mongodb connections or new mongodb Atlas ones.

(I have an express node forum running and its hosted on Atlas cloud db)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand that MongoDB Atlas is a Cloud platform for MongoDB, so the database lives somewhere in the cloud, e.g. AWS.

While Docker network is a local network that Docker creates for you to encapsulate different containers into one net, thus making it possible to communicate between each other, and by the same token be isolated from world.

The answer is that you cannot make MongoDB Atlas part of your Docker network, because Atlas is not a Container that you could embed into your network. But the good news that you don't need to, because you can connect to the Atlas instance anyways from any computer, in condition that configuration of your Atlas allows to establish connections.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!

So in this setup your point is that it cannot be dockerized in some way? Whats the best way in your opinion to transfer my app+db to some other guy?

I have checked docker and maybe vm linux but im not really experienced to tell.

Comment: Well, if you want to dockerize your application, you can still dockerize your Node.js application, and deploy it. While the application can access the database it will work. 

If you want to dockerize both App + DB you could try creating another docker container with MongoDB in it, but this will bring more operational burdance for you. 

VM Linux is a prehistoric tool to Docker. It won't solve your problem either.

My point is that you don't need and cannot dockerize MongoDB in an Atlas, just dockerize your app and deploy it whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can dockerize `Node.js` application and also provide a mongoDB service that your app should connect as Mongo Atlas is not on your local machine. Its somewhere on the cloud. Refer the `compose.yaml` file snippet below:

```
version: "3"

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      <ENV_VARIABLE_FOR_MONGO_URI>: "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.zjlh1.mongodb.net/<db-name>"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```